# TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType

Tags: python, typeerror, pickle

I am trying to make a multisave function. This is the code I used
(And I know, `global` is not a proper coding, but whatever):

```
global game
game = None

global file
file = None

# stuff...

def saveGame():
    print('► Saving game...')
    with open(file, 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(PlayerIG, f, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
    print('► Game saved. You can access it by typing "load" at the title.')    

def loadGame():
    print('► Loading saved game...')
    if os.path.exists(file) == True: # TypeError on this line
        with open(file, 'rb') as f:
            global PlayerIG
            PlayerIG = pickle.load(f)        
        print('► Game loaded.')
        MainMenu()
    else:
        print('The savefile doesn\'t exist!')
        TitleScreen()


fileOpt = input()
if fileOpt == 'back':
    TitleScreen()
if fileOpt == '1' or '2' or '3' or '4':
    if fileOpt == '1':
        file = 'TGHA1.pickle'
    if fileOpt == '2':
        file = 'TGHA2.pickle'
    if fileOpt == '3':
        file = 'TGHA3.pickle'
    if fileOpt == '4':
        file = 'TGHA4.pickle'            
    if os.path.exists(file) == True:
        # code...

        subFileOpt = input()
        if subFileOpt == 'load':
            loadGame()
        if subFileOpt == 'delete':
            # code...

            delFileOpt = input()
            if delFileOpt == 'yes':
                print('► Deleting file...')
                os.remove(file)
                print('► File deleted!')
                TitleScreen()

# mainly invalid input stuff down from here...
```

The problem is, when I go to the line where `# TypeError on this line` (may also be same for the `loadGame()` function, it raises this error:

```
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
```

I know what it means, but how would I fix it?

Comment: `fileOpt == '1' or '2' or '3' or '4'` doesn’t make sense, so `file` might not be set even if that block is entered.

Comment: @Ryan I tried that, and yet it still doesn't work.

Comment: Before calling `loadGame()`, `print(file)`. If the output is `None`, delete everything after that, plus the functions. First step to making a minimal example.